# C# Setup Project OS Compability Problem

Tags: c#, operating-system, setup-project

I'm having trouble with my Setup Project in Visual Studio 2008. I'm compiling my project and building my Setup Files on .NetFramework 3,5. My operating system is XP Pro x86 SP3[ENG]. When i try to install my project's setup and run my C# application in current OS, everything goes in right way.

But on the other side, when i attempt to install my project's setup on another operating system, like; XP Pro x86 in different language [GER] SP2 or Windows 7 x86, i have a fails with different background color on some buttons or had tabcontrols without any text on it and these kind of visual property problems.

I've already seached on it but couldn't found anything valuable and need your tips and experience.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1):

you should add localizations to your setup user interface or specify that you want to use always the same resources (English) also when running on other languages (German).